# Aggregating a simple COUNT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am formulating a MySQL query that tries to aggregate a COUNT.
The data looks like this....table is "workers"

```
   NAME      DPT
   -----     ----
   CLARK     10
   JAMES     10
   ALLEN     10
   ADAMS     20
   WU        20
   MARTIN    30
   FITZ      30
   SCHMIDT   30
   MILLER    30
```

I need to list the table like this with a count in the departments

```
   NAME      DPT   CNT
   -----     ----   ---
   CLARK     10     3
   JAMES     10     3
   ALLEN     10     3
   ADAMS     20     2
   WU        20     2
   MARTIN    30     4
   FITZ      30     4
   SCHMIDT   30     4
   MILLER    30     4
```

I tried this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(NAME), DPT, COUNT(DPT) as CNT FROM workers GROUP BY DPT;
```

with no success. Pretty sure it's something simple but I'm stumped. Any ideas on where I am going wrong? - JW

Answer (score 2):

Since the count aggregation is on the `DPT` field only you need to have a subquery for that and then join with the `workers` table to get the names.

```
SELECT w.NAME, w.DPT, tot.CNT
FROM workers AS w JOIN (SELECT DPT, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM workers GROUP BY DPT) AS tot ON w.DPT = tot.DPT 
ORDER BY w.DPT, w.NAME;
```

Comment: +1, This join would be faster than my subquery, but I'd recommend using an explicit join to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks @Devon, changed it to use an explicit JOIN as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When you group, you aggregate all the rows under that field.  Therefore, you'll only get rows for each distinct value of DPT.

You could use a subquery to get the count for the same DPT value.

```
SELECT NAME, DPT, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM workers w2 WHERE w2.DPT = workers.DPT) as CNT
FROM workers;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed `COUNT`(MySQL 8.0 and above):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY dpt) AS cnt
FROM workers;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1584c876f86eba2e1337c94636d67595)**